# ElasticSearch + NEST Bulk Searching

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm developing a utility through which searches can be submitted in bulk via batches.  I was wondering whether the ElasticSearch 6.xxx /Nest API has built-in capabilities for bulk searching, rather than having to enumerate and perform each search individually?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here, i have not used it tho so i cant tell you how it works. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

Comment: @aHochstein Thanks man, that looks exactly like what I was searching for!  Perhaps post it as an answer so I can award you points for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elastic provides a multi search api, you can take a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html).

Comment: NEST exposes this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/Search/MultiSearch/ElasticClient-MultiSearch.cs

Comment: @RussCam the link is broken. Are these [examples from Tests](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/tests/Tests/Search/MultiSearch/MultiSearchApiTests.cs) what are you referring to? Also, what is the max no. of results returned by MultiSearch? Performance wise, for querying large datasets, what do you recommend: MultiSearch or [ScrollAll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/scrolling-documents.html#scrollall-observable) in Parallel.ForEach?